# Calling a MDI Child's method from the MDI Parent in C# 1

Tags: c#, mdi

In first step login form in MDI container. It works well. After login next Message form show "out of" MDI container. I want to show also message form in MDI container.

```
    // MDI code
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 login = new Form2();
        login.MdiParent = this;
        login.Show();            
    }
    // Login button code
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "admin" && textBox2.Text == "123")
        {
            Form3 message = new Form3();                
            this.Hide();
            message.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by inside, do you mean the messagebox owner should be the mid container, or you mean you want it to be inside the borders of the mdi container?

Comment: when you're saying Message, are you actually referring to `Form3`, which you named `message`? Or are you referring to an actual MessageBox?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to show the form inside the MDI container then do

```
    message.MdiParent = login.MdiParent;
```